# reacts conditional rendering, to return array in render, react 16

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to return  an array elements in render, inside return function.
If I use:

```
 <div>
```

like containers works well, it was  working like this originally, if I delete the conditional lines:

```
{ index === 0 && subindex===0 &&
}
```

works well too:

I get the error on the conditional previous line:

```
Syntax error: Unexpected token, expected
```

here my code:

```
    return [
      { index === 0 && subindex===0 &&
        <a href="#" onClick={() => fields.remove(subindex)}>
          <ShowIcon size="25" color="darkred" icon="removecircleblack"/>
        </a>,
      }

      <Field
        key={fieldKey}
        name={`${rowValues}.${fieldKey}`}
        type={subfield.typeInput ? subfield.typeInput : 'text'}
        typeInput={subfield.typeInput ? subfield.typeInput : 'text'}
        component={FormField}
        placeHolder={subfield.placeHolder ? t(`form.${fieldParentKey}-${fieldKey}`) : ''}
        listSource={subfield.listSource ? aSources[subfield.listSource] : ''}
        index={subindex + 1}
        width="270px"
        icon={subfield.icon}
      />
    ];
```

what i'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `{}` around the condition, it will work. `{}` is required to put the js expressions inside JSX, if you use it at other places then it means you are trying to return an **Object**.

Write it like this:

```
return [
    index === 0 && subindex===0 ?
      <a href="#" onClick={() => fields.remove(subindex)}>
        <ShowIcon size="25" color="darkred" icon="removecircleblack"/>
      </a>
      :null,

    <Field
      key={fieldKey}
      name={`${rowValues}.${fieldKey}`}
      type={subfield.typeInput ? subfield.typeInput : 'text'}
      typeInput={subfield.typeInput ? subfield.typeInput : 'text'}
      component={FormField}
      placeHolder={subfield.placeHolder ? t(`form.${fieldParentKey}-${fieldKey}`) : ''}
      listSource={subfield.listSource ? aSources[subfield.listSource] : ''}
      index={subindex + 1}
      width="270px"
      icon={subfield.icon}
    />
];
```